# Redirect context root with UrlRewriteFilter

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, servlet-filters, tuckey-urlrewrite-filter

I have web application which I want to deploy to weblogic and I added `UrlRewriteFilter`

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logLevel</param-name>
        <param-value>DEBUG</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>UrlRewriteFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

I also defined following rule:

```
<rule>
    <note>the context root should be redirected by appending a / to the path</note>
    <from>%{context-path}</from>
    <to type="redirect">%{context-path}/</to>
</rule>
```

I'd like to redirect context root in Weblogic in similar way as it is possible in Tomcat.

See [Redirect context root in Weblogic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47312119/redirect-context-root-in-weblogic) for more details

When I deploy the application and try to access http://localhost:7001/my-application, I get:

```
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Conf DEBUG: now initialising conf
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRule ERROR: Rule Rule 0 had error: from (%{context-path}) is an invalid expression - java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0
%{context-path}
^ 
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase ERROR: from (%{context-path}) is an invalid expression - java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal repetition near index 0
%{context-path}
^
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.RuleBase DEBUG: loaded rule Rule 0 (%{context-path}, %{context-path}/ 0)
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.NormalRule DEBUG: failed to load rule
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.Conf DEBUG: conf status false
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: inited with 1 rules
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter DEBUG: conf is NOT ok
org.tuckey.web.filters.urlrewrite.UrlRewriteFilter ERROR: Conf failed to load
```

I also understand that my filter has `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>`, so it'll capture both URLs (with trailing slash and without)

Is it possible to achieve what I described with http://www.tuckey.org/urlrewrite/

If yes, how?

If no, why?

Answer (score 0):

Your **`<from>`** tag is incorrect. Hope this will help

If your **`context-path`** is **`"myApp"`**

```
<rule>
    <from>^(.*)$</from>
    <to type="redirect" context="myApp">$1/</to>
</rule>
```

If your **`context-path`** is **`""`**, i.e **`empty`** then you do not need to write any rule to forward the request to the context, because by default the request will be forwarded to default context